# Usar variável PHP no Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Ao clicar no quadro positivo (indicado na figura por uma seta), o usuário aceita o convite de amizade.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso passar o id do usuário (valor 15) para a página atualizar-amigos.php . O evento é realizado pela página convites.js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#aceitar").click(function(){
     var id = ????????? ;
        $.post('atualizar-amigos.php', {amigo:id}, function(){
            $(".item").remove();
        });
    });
});
```

O id do usuário está armazenada na variável PHP $user_id. Eu tentei:

```
var id = <?= $user_id?>;
var id = <?php echo $user_id; ?>;
var id = "<?php echo $user_id; ?>";
```

Nas 2 primeiras opções, dá erro. Na terceira, o valor passado é

```
"<?php echo $user_id;?>"
```

(e não o valor 15)

Também criei o JSON $frind (impresso na imagem) e tentei:

```
var id = frind['id'];
```

Mas tbm não funcionou. Como eu acesso o valor id (no JSON) OU a variável PHP ($user_id) na função post do Ajax?

Comment: já respondeu a própria pergunta.. `var id = "<?php echo $user_id; ?>";`

Comment: Você fez esses testes direto no arquivo PHP que contém o HTML ou em um arquivo JS? Pois parece que o PHP não foi interpretado no arquivo, o que indica que o código não está em um arquivo PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia colocar um atributo na input checkbox, para armazenar o id do usuario. Depois quando a checkbox fosse selecionado você pegava esse atributo com a função attr do jquery e mandava na requisição ajax. Veja esse pequeno exemplo (com pequenas modificações para torna-lo o menor possivel):

html.php

```
<!-- Elementos -->
<div>
<!-- Suponha um codigo php arbitrario -->
<?php
//esses dados vem de algum lugar (talvez do banco de dados)
$amigo_id = 25;
?>

    Aceitar <input class="aceitar" type="checkbox" user_id="<?php echo $amigo_id; ?>">

    <div id="resposta">
    A resposta vai aparecer aqui!
    </div>
</div>


<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $(".aceitar").change(function(){

                if(this.checked){
                var id =  $(this).attr('user_id');
                    $.post('atualizar-amigos.php', {amigo: id}, function(response){
                        //$(".item").remove();
                    $("#resposta").html(response);
                });     
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Arquivo atualizar-amigos.php

```
<?php
echo 'amigos atualizados! Apenas um teste. Novo id: ' . $_POST['amigo'];
```

É claro que o atualizar-amigos.php pode vir a retornar um objeto json caso você necessite.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade são imagens e não checkbox, mas a solução que fiz é muito similar. Na html eu fiz um input hidden:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="campo" value="<?php echo $user_id;?>" />
```

E no arquivo js:

```js
var id = document.getElementById("campo").value;
```